# null value in column "list_name" violates not-null constraint DETAIL:

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, postman

[image]I created a function makeList to insert items into the list.Whenever I try to check the API through postman for a POST request, I get the following error
`null value in column "list_name" violates not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row contains (16, null).`

Views Function

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        list_item = request.POST.get('list_item')
        ListCategory.objects.create(list_name=list_item)

        # return something not yet decided
    full_list = ListCategory.objects.order_by('id')

    full_list = serializers.serialize('json',full_list)
    return HttpResponse(full_list, content_type='application/json')
```

Model ListCategory

```
class ListCategory(models.Model):
    # user_id = models.IntegerField()
    list_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.list_name
```

Postman Screenshot given above

Comment: show the model `ListCategory`

Comment: In postman, you need to send post data in the body but you are sending it in  params.  So when you are getting the data in`list_item = request.POST.get('list_item')`, you will get `None`.

Comment: How should I send it then?

Comment: In postman, there are different tabs, Params, Authorization, Headers, Body etc. Navigate to the body tab and there you add the key-value pairs and send.